# Assign a new column in a multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following multi-indexed dataframe:

[image: Multi-indexed dataframe]

I want to add a new column labeled `returns` and assign the percentage change applied to the `close` column i.e

```
bars.loc[symbol, 'returns'] = bars.loc[symbol]['close'].pct_change()
```

The challenge is that the `returns` column does not get populated as expected. So with the snippet below, here is what I got

```
for symbol in symbols:
   bars.loc[symbol, 'returns'] = bars.loc[symbol]['close'].pct_change()
print(df.loc[symbols[0]].tail())
```

[image]

The returns column has NaN as their values, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the values to the new column. Assuming the DF is bars and symbol index is level_0 then for the loop, you can use the code below. This assumes you want 10.0 as the return % and not 0.1.

```
idx_list = bars.index.levels[0]

for symbol in idx_list:
        x = bars.loc[symbol, 'close'].pct_change()*100
        bars.loc[symbol, 'returns'] = x.values
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: Multi-indices can be somewhat tricky and it seems not so comprehensively documented. Need to be careful about the object types being accessed and assigned.